# AND - OR Operators not working?

Tags: php

This is killing me, and probably I'm just making a typo that I can't see.

Why is this validation not working?

```
<?php

$db = 'database';
$host = 'host';
$port = port;
$usr = 'username';
$pwd = 'password';
$db_status = array(
  'global_status'=>"",
  'slave_status'=>array()
);

$db = new mysqli(
      $host, $usr, $pwd, NULL, $port
  );

$qry = "SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Slave_running'";

$stmt = $db->query($qry);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
  $db_status['global_status']=$row['Value'];
}

$qry = "SHOW SLAVE STATUS";

$stmt = $db->query($qry);

while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
  $db_status['slave_status'] = $row;
}

$gbst = $db_status['global_status'];
$siostate = $db_status['slave_status']['Slave_IO_State'];
$siorunning = $db_status['slave_status']['Slave_IO_Running'];
$ssqlrunning = $db_status['slave_status']['Slave_SQL_Running'];
$lastioErrno = $db_status['slave_status']['Last_IO_Errno'];
$lastioError = $db_status['slave_status']['Last_IO_Error'];
$lastiotimestamp = $db_status['slave_status']['Last_IO_Error_Timestamp'];

if ($gbst === "OFF" || 
  $siostate !== "Running" || 
  $siorunning !== "Yes" ||
  $ssqlrunning !== "Yes") {
```

I am getting an error in the console reading:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$siostate' (T_VARIABLE) in
>   /home/esantos/Crons/check_database_slave.php on line 50

Any ideas?

Comment: The code you are showing seems fine; the error must reside in a part of the code you're not showing us. Provide a [mcve], maybe?

Comment: Looks like you've got some kind of special character in there

Comment: Copy & Pasted your code, it worked for me, something that comes before it is most likely the cause.

Comment: I updated the question with the complete code until the point it breaks, the problem is on the if statement.

Comment: You have no quotes on port `$port = port;`

Comment: @BarryThomas I just put the word port there to not include the actual value, but it is written correctly in my code.

Comment: I'm not sure so, but I tried this `$gbst = "OFF";
$siostate = "Run";
$siorunning = "No";
$ssqlrunning = "No";

if ($gbst === "OFF" || 
  $siostate !== "Running" || 
  $siorunning !== "Yes" ||
  $ssqlrunning !== "Yes")
{
 echo "Hello";
}else{
 echo "Goodbye";
}`
and it works for me.

Comment: I was under the impression PHP doesn't really mind about spaces, but what I did is I removed a blank space that existed after each double pipe (||) and that did the trick. I'm unsure as to what happened here.

Im skeptical to believe it had something to do with a special character, since I wrote the code myself (not any copy paste).